# How is a password to decrypt a file verified?

Tags: security, pdf, encryption, hash, passwords

Let's say I have a password-protected PDF file, `mypdf.pdf`, with the password `'1234'`. When I enter the password into the PDF reader to decrypt it, how does the software know I entered the correct password?

My understanding is that when I enter in a password an operation is performed on all of the bytes inside the PDF file using the entered password as the key. So even if I enter the *wrong* password the data is still being transformed, with the incorrect key.

My question is how the software can distinguish between data that is the result of a correct password being typed in and data that is the result of a wrong password.

Answer (score 1):

The content of a PDF document is not decrypted unless an authentication algorithm passes.

These algorithms are defined in e.g [PDF 32000-1:2008](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) - 7.6.3.4 Password Algorithms.

In simple words: When creating an encrypted PDF the user and owner password are used to calculate static values (O, U, OE and UE) which were saved in the PDF file itself. The authentication is a "simple" process of recreating these values by the given password and comparing them with the static values in the PDF file.